# How can I reuse this code for multiple elements?

Tags: jquery

I have a function that paginates data. I have two tables on the same page that need pagination. I want to reuse the function for both tables if possible. I've tried to use the script for both tables, but when I call the script the second time, the data from the first call seems to be wiped out and the second call is what prevails.

Why Is this happening?

```
  $.fn.scroller = function(options) {
    var settings = {
      ele   : '',
      limit : 10,
      offset: 0,
      error : 'No More Posts!',
      delay : 500,
      scroll: true
    }

    if(options) {
      $.extend(settings, options);
    }

    return this.each(function() {
      $this      = $(this);
      $settings  = settings;
      var offset = $settings.offset;


      if($settings.scroll == true) $initmessage = 'Scroll for more or click here';
      else $initmessage = 'Click for more';
      $this.append('<tbody id="adi"></tbody><tfoot><tr><td id="more" colspan="2">'+$initmessage+'</tr></tr></tfoot>');

      function getData() {
        $.post('test.asp',{
          ele:$settings.ele,
          limit:$settings.limit,
          offset:offset,
        },
        function(data){
          $this.find('#more').html($initmessage);
          if(data == ""){
            $this.find('#more').html($settings.error);
          }else{
            offset = offset + $settings.limit;
            $this.find('#adi').append(data);
          }
        });
      }
      getData();

      if($settings.scroll == true){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
          if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $this.height()){
            $this.find('#more').html('Loading Posts');
            setTimeout(function() {
              getData();
            }, $settings.delay);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Here are the calls to the function

```
  $('#test1').scroller({
    ele:'test1',
    limit:60,
    offset:0,
    error:'End Articles',
    delay: 500,
    scroll:false
  });

  $('#test2').scroller({
    ele:'test2',
    limit:5,
    offset:0,
    error:'End Blogs',
    delay: 500,
    scroll:false
  });
```

**Edit:**

This is the actual HTML

```
  <table id="test1">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And:

```
  <table id="test2">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your table HTML?

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, but you might consider checking out http://www.datatables.net/, which is a really cool table formatter.  Related to your question, what do you mean "the second table prevails"?

Comment: Thanks, Charles. I've used DataTables in the past and really like it. It's a little bloated for what I need I think. What I was saying up top was basically, the first call (#test1) data that I am sending in to the `scroller` function is wiped out, or overwritten by `test2`. So, only the test2 table populates with data. If I copy the JQuery code verbatim and just rename the function in the second file I just created, I can get both tables to populate with data. I just don't like doing it like that. There has to be a better way

Comment: So, in the case outlined above, `#test1` never gets populated, but `#test2` does?

Comment: No Charles, I haven't confirmed it. I'm really a noob with JQuery. If you tell me what to look for, I'll have a look. Also, just to clarify, if I comment out the second call (test2) to the plugin, test1 will populate. It's weird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56007/discussion-between-charles-wood-and-nan).